# Excel, Want to Create Dropdown Based on a "yes" Cell

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

The issue is pretty simple, but I can't seem to solve it or find an answer.

I have one cell A2 that activates with a yes/no based on what the user enters elsewhere.

I would like to create a drop-down list in another cell A3 only if A2 has a "yes" inside.  From what I can tell, this can only be done with Data Validation, but it keeps throwing errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Data Validation for a drop down list, when you are creating it, you can use "If" statements.  Choose "List" from "allow", then for the Source, something like `=if(A2="Yes",B2:B6,C2)`.  Note, I assumed that your list of data is B2:B6, and in C2 is some string you want to return if A2 is not "Yes".

Note: If A2 is not "Yes", and you want the list in A3 to then say "No list necessary", you can't just use that string in the IF statement for the validation - you need to put that string in, i.e. C2, and use the formula above. Can't put strings in the data validation IF statement for some reason.

Comment: Perfect!  I was trying to have the result be "" if the data validation failed, but referencing a cell with "" instead works!  tyvm!

Comment: @JeyLegarie - glad to help!  If this is the answer, would you mind marking it as such (click the check mark under the up/down arrows).

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Oh well It appears VBA was completely unnecessary for this use. I'm not deleting the answer because it would work, but I don't reccomend this over the easier method!

I would use VBA for that. If you aren't afraid to get dirty with some code, here's something I believe will work. If you are an absolute zero in VBA I can give more detailed help.

Open up the Visual Basic Editor and copy/paste this:

```
'this means it activates when there is change in your worksheet:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)         
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then 'Checks that the change occurs in the cell A2       

        If Range("A2") = "Yes" Then 'only enters this if it changed to yes
            With Range("A3").Validation 'this little block creates the list. More on this after the code
                .delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:="=Paramètres!$C$1:$C$5"
            End With 
        End If

        If Range("A2") = "No" Then 'only does this if it changed to no
            Range("A3").Validation.delete 'this deletes the list.                    
        End If

    End if
End sub
```

So the list, in our case, is created or deleted when a change occurs in cell A2. The list contains the items you will have to write in cells C1 to C5. (example: In c1 write "hello", in c2 write:"goodbye" etc). If you want more or less inputs you can change C1 to C3 or C10, as you like. You can also make put the list elsewhere (column E for example) by changing the C. After writing your list in a column, I suggest hiding that column because it is unnecessary to see it.